# Can't delete a file that exists but I cannot see

Tags: java, macos

I have seen this question before and attempted to use the garbage collector, but that did not work for me.

I used the `mkdirs()` method to create a set of directories. Java reports that they exist, yet I cannot see them on my system where they should be. I am using Mac OS X Yosemite, so I do not know if this is a Mac-specific issue or a bug in Java.

My code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileChecker {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      File file = new File("~/MyDirectory"); // in my home folder

      System.out.println("Exists: " + file.exists()); // true
      System.out.println("Can read: " + file.canRead()); // true
      System.out.println("Can write: " + file.canWrite()); // true
      System.out.println("Can execute: " + file.canExecute()); // true

      System.gc();

      System.out.println("Deleted: " + file.delete()); // still false
   }
}
```

When I open my home directory `~` in Finder, the folder does not appear. Doing an `ls` in Terminal also yields nothing.

Comment: Do you have permissions to delete it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  File file = new File("~/MyDirectory"); // in my home folder
```

"~" is special to shells like `bash` and certain other programs that choose to give it a special meaning. It's not meaningful to `java.io.File` or to the operating system itself. The `File` object which you've created here refers a directory literally named "~" within the java process's current working directory, and then to something named "MyDirectory" within this literally named "~" directory.

Try adding this line to your program:

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

This will print out the actual path to the file which java is using. Once you know where this "MyDirectory" really is, it may become obvious why you can't delete it. It may be a directory which isn't empty, for example.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I am using `System.getProperty("user.home")` now instead.

Answer (score 3):

`File#delete()` is an old java 1 era method that doesn't give you any information for why it couldn't delete.

Try using [JAVA 7 Files.delete(Path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29)  which will throw an `IOException` with the reason why it failed.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but +1 for pointing them to a better method. File.delete() sucks for this very reason. Can't tell you how many times over the years i've wondered wth the problem was and was given next to no information from the JVM.

Comment: Good reference. It throws a few different exceptions such as `DirectoryNotEmptyException` which turned out to be the problem. But the overarching issue (why I couldn't find the directory in the first place) was because it was getting created in my NetBeans project home, not my user home. Guess I should use `System.getProperty("user.home")` instead.